# How to make ImageButton not clickable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a number of ImageButtons within a repeater, depending on each record some of these images will be clickable and others, I have disabled the button to stop postback.

I have now changed the opacity of each image so that unless you are hovering on that imagebutton it will be 0.6. The trouble is, for those that I have disabled, obviously I cannot alter the opacity on/off hover.

Currently I am doing this:

```
    if (vessel.IsRegistered)
    {
        imagebuttonRegistration.ImageUrl = ("../Images/Icons/registrationApproved.gif");
        imagebuttonRegistration.CommandArgument = null;
        DisableImageButton(imagebuttonRegistration);                
        imagebuttonRegistration.ToolTip = GetLocalResourceObject("imageButRegistrationRegisteredText").ToString();
    }

public static void DisableImageButton(ImageButton imagebutton)
{
    imagebutton.Attributes.Remove("href");
    imagebutton.Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");            
}
```

But as disabling the button is now causing me problems, how might I just stop the button being clickable/no postback but allow the other attributes to be used.

Comment: possibly alternate would be `imagebutton.Attributes.Add("onclick","return false");  `

Comment: Yes this works however it still appears to be a clickable link, which may cause confusion. What I mean by appears is the cursor still changes to a hand on hover.

Comment: @SelectDistinct, you could change the cursor to pointer by using Css perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different way using Css:

In your css file add:

```
.notclickable{
    cursor:text;    
}
```

And in DisableImageButton method add:

```
imagebutton.Attributes["class"] ="notclickable";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
imagebutton.Attributes.Add("onclick","return false");
imagebutton.Style.Add("cursor","context-menu");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS

```
.imagebutton:disabled {
     opacity:0.7;
 }
```

check this out:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp